# How manage dependencies between class into coffeescript project

Tags: class, coffeescript, dependencies

There is the **sample** :

- ClassB
- ClassA extends ClassB

**command** : coffee -w -j main.js -c -l -o lib src

**error** : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

**reason** : ClassA is compiled before B in the compiled file so classB don't exist yet when 
ClassA is create and try to extend it..

**stupid fix** : ClassA rename to ClassC, so it will be compiled after ClassB in the compiled file

Some one get a better fix ?

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated at [coffeescript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#usage):

> -j, --join [FILE]
>   Before compiling, concatenate all scripts together in the order they were passed, and write them into the specified file. Useful for building large projects.

This means that you have to pass the scripts with the right order. Assuming that classA is in file classA.coffee and classB in file classB.coffee, command above should be:

```
coffee -w -j main.js -c -l -o lib src/classB.coffee src/classA.coffee
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is it's not automatic and on very large project it's a problem. For the moment I rename ClassB to AClassB, not perfect but it's automatic..